# Походження виразу "сидіти в печінках"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Приклад вживання - "Ти мені вже в печінках сидиш".

[Словник фразеологізмів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53409/361236.html)

> ***сиді́ти в печінка́х*** кому. Набридати, ставати неприємним, нестерпним.

Цікавить походження даного фразеологізму?

Comment: може чимось допоможе. 1) ".... печінки означали первісно всілякі нутрощі, які можна було пекти та їсти. ...  Все це можна прочитати в ЕСУМ і ЭССЯ." [(c)beilendekunst](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/309212.html) 2) разг. сидіти в печінках у кого, **в’їстися (уїстися) в печінки кому** [(з словнику ідіом)](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/s).

Answer (score 2):

Зазвичай про походження народних фразеологізмів немає багато інформації, однак дещо вдалося знайти. В "[Галицько-Волинському літописі](http://litopys.org.ua/hens1/hn06.htm)" пише:

> Вислів "прояти на печенехъ" знаходить повний відповідник у сучасному
>   вислові, зареєстрованому в волинських діалектах (с. Городно,
>   Головнянського р-ну): допекти до печінок. І. Франко реєструє в
>   Галичині: «ти мені печінки виїв» (І. Франко, XXIV, 482). Номис
>   подібних висловів з компонентом «печінка» не знає. Б. Грінченко подає
>   за Шевченком — в печінках сидіти, що цілком відповідає вислову
>   волинського літописця (див. Грінченко: печінка). У Даля подібного
>   вислову не знаходимо. **Отже, можна думати, що це речèння-штамп було
>   особливо поширене в південноруських діалектах.**

Також є інформація у праці "[Фразеологічна символіка: лінгвокультурологічний аспект](http://www.levchenko.eu/images/pobierz/GRUDEN-Levchenko.pdf)":

> Серед соматичних символів, які здебільшого тотожні в порівнюваних
>   мовах, цікаві відмінності спостережено у функціонуванні та
>   символічному навантаженні слова укр. **печінка**. У словнику Д.Ушакова
>   зазначено, що рос.печенка **вживають як символ гніву, роздратування,
>   жовчного настрою**[Уш, т.3, с.250]. М.Новикова вважає,  що  символіці 
>   печінки  як  синонімові  життя,  життєвої  енергії,  а  іноді  й
>   “місця перебування” емоційних станів, притаманна універсальність [166,
>   с.244]. При  всій  тотожності  українського  й  російського  символів
>   печінка  / печенка, українські  фразеологічні  словники  фіксують 
>   значно  більше  ФО  з  цим компонентом, їх варіантів: пор. укр. сидіти
>   в печінках кому [ФСУМ, с.802] – рос. сидит в печенках  у  кого  [ФСРЯ,
>   с.423] ...  укр. відбити  печінки  [ФСУМ,  с.115] –  рос. (все) 
>   печенки  отбить, отшибить [БАС, т.9, с.1144] ... укр.брати за  печінки
>   –  рос. за  печенку  берет‘раздражает,  сердит’  [Уш,  т.3, с.250]; до
>   (самых)  печенок,  до  (самой)  печенки  (продрог,  измок)[БАС,  т.9,
>   с.1144]; говорить  печенкой,  не  гнѣвайся  печенку  испортишь  [Даль,
>   т.3, с.109] –  біл. пячонка  пячэцца[МРБСП] –  пор.  укр. Гнів  кров 
>   псує.  Утовкують  сердитого [Франко, т.16, вип.2, с.347]. Низку
>   українських ФО з аналізованим компонентом продовжують одиниці:
>   **вивертати печінки**, **витрясти печінки**, **в’їстися в печінки**(пор.рос.выматывать кишки–  біл. вантробы пераядаць, нутро
>   паліць, кішкі пераядаць,  гізунты  выцягваць,  вантробы  выцягваць 
>   (даставаць)[МРБСП];вантробы  ад’есці ‘прычыніць  душэўныя  пакуты,
>   надакучыць  каму’  [СБНФ, с.35]); **диявол  в  печінки**,  **лізти  в 
>   печінки**,  **мара  в  печінки**,  **насадити  в  печінки**, **пекти в
>   самі печінки**, **трясця йому в печінки**, **тягне за печінки**; **як
>   на печінки**; **матері  в  печінку**;  **щоб  мені  печінку 
>   роздуло**,  **добратися  до  самих  печінок**, **допікати до живих
>   печінок** тощо [ФСУМ, с.626]. В  українській фразеологічній системі
>   існує одиниця, яка не має вказаного символічного значення, а створена
>   на основі  актуалізації  слоту  “колір”:  укр. посинів, як печінка 
>   ‘дуже  змерз’  [ССНП, с.115].